# How to change opacity of certain number of button(x) while not writing them out one by one? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I don't think I asked the question quite well, so here's an explanation. I want to create buttons invisibly when Form1 loads, instead of changing them each individually, is there a way to change all of them with fewer lines of code?

Note: I do not want to change **all** buttons, only a certain range of them.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Visible = true;
        button2.Visible = true;
        button3.Visible = true;
        button4.Visible = true;
        button5.Visible = true;
        button6.Visible = true;
        button7.Visible = true;
    }
```

By that I mean, is it possible to change those buttons visibility to true without writing them out one by one?

```
button1 - button7.Visible = true;
```

something like this..

Comment: Is this WinForms?

Comment: windows forms app (.net framework)

Comment: Look up "for loops".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to change only a certain range of buttons, assuming they're all simply called button[x] you could create a function like this:

```
    private void toggleButtons(int start, int end, bool trueOrFalse)
    {
        for(int x=start; x <= end; x++)
        {
            this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Name == "button" + x.ToString()).SingleOrDefault().Visible = trueOrFalse;
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it like this using (startNo,endNo,true/false for visibility)

```
toggleButtons(1, 7, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change visibility of all buttons in the form, you could do so.

```
foreach(var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
   button.Visible = false; // or true, depending what you want to set
}
```

If you do no want to change visibility of all Buttons in Form and if you need to filter buttons, based on some criteria, you could do so as well.
For example, if you want to filter buttons whose names starts with "specialButton",

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(x=>x.Name.StartsWith("specialButton")))
{
   button.Visible = false;
}
```

Similarly, you can filter based on other properties as well.

Another option is to enlist the buttons that needs to be changed in a list. For example, if you need to change only button1 and button2 from a form comprising of 10 buttons, you could

```
var list = new[] { button1, button2 };
foreach (var item in list)
{
   item.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: no, i mean changing visibility of certain buttons in form, instead of all of them.

Comment: Do you have criteria on them ? say all of them have a pecular naming pattern, are in a panel or have something attached to Tag Property ?

Comment: second option or third ? The second option meant if you have special naming pattern for the buttons that needs to be changed. The second one involve creating a list , that has all the special buttons listed, and then iterating over the list to change the visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Controls`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netframework-4.7.2) property to get all of the controls on a form. For example:

```
foreach(var button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: i dont want to change all buttons invisible, i want to change a certain amount of them invisible.

Comment: Your question says *all* buttons, how are we supposed to know what you mean?

Comment: That still doesn't help, how can we know *which* controls you are referring to?

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean

Comment: You want to make *some* buttons not visible right? Well how do you identify *which* ones? That's not a hard question.

Comment: i identify them by their names in the form like Button1, Button2 etc